# PDB file missing when trying to run Firebase on a Flutter project [LNK4099, LNK2019, LNK2001]

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, lnk2019, lnk2001

PDB files not found when trying to run Firebase on a Flutter project.

I'm trying to run a Flutter app on VS Code. I set up Firebase, added a google-services.json file to my root folder and I've installed the following dependencies:cloud_firestore, firebase_auth, firebase_core and firebase_storage.

However, I'm getting the following errors when I debug it:
firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_desktop.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_desktop.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]

firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_log.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_log.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]

firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_options.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_options.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]

firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_common.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_app_common.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]

firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_mutex_windows.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_mutex_windows.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]

firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_date_provider.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_date_provider.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]

firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_heartbeat_controller_desktop.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_heartbeat_controller_desktop.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]

firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_log_stdio.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'firebase_app.pdb' was not found with 'firebase_app.lib(d94e1bff3c0e8414a6679ea91c3e103e_firebase_app.dir_Debug_log_stdio.obj)' or at 'C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\Debug\firebase_app.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info [C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\instagram_flutter\build\windows\plugins\firebase_core\firebase_core_plugin.vcxproj]

and errors LNK2019, LNK2001. I don't have any pdb file saved.

Could someone please guide me as to how to get around this error? Thank you. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue myself.

You're most likely missing "Desktop Development with C++" with your Visual Studio installation.

Additional pointers:

- It's likely best to have only one of `Visual Studio` or `Visual Studio Build Tools` installed. There's not much point in duplicating the toolset on a development workstation. I opted to uninstall `Visual Studio Build Tools`.
- If you do have `Visual Studio Build Tools` installed alongside Visual Studio, then don't mix-and-match different years of `Visual Studio` and `Visual Studio Build Tools` - ex: 2019 + 2022. Use the same editions, like 2022 + 2022.